# Sorting a dictionary but got "List Indices must be int, not tuple" error

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to use the sorted() function as OrderedDict is not available for me (python 2.6.6). However I get this "List indices must be int, not tuple" error

I tried to just used sorted() function on a dictionary and it works fine when i try with some dummy values, but im not sure why it doesn't work on my specific code.

```
   venue_dict = {}
   for venues in venue_names:
       venue_dict[venues] = False
   venue_dict = sorted(venue_dict)
```

I get this *TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str*

so i create a dictionary with a value False for each venue. (venue_names is a list of all venue names) The false is just used as a flag value.

anyways I try to print the sorted dictionary but receive the tuple error. 
Anyone know why? I tried googling this up but haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Please include the full error traceback as that can help us to help you better.

Answer (score 2):

The built-in [sorted()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) function doesn't work on dictionaries with the default parameters, because the default sort key will be the (key, value) pair. This is a tuple, not a sortable item.

You can ensure that the dictionary key is used as a sort key via a lambda function:

```py
mydict = sorted(mydict, key=lambda k: k[0])  # just the key from the (key, value) tuple
```

Alternatively, you can sort directly on the dictionary's items:

```py
mydict = sorted(mydict.items())
```

The statements above will return lists of tuples however. If you want an actual ordered dictionary, you'll have to use an `OrderedDict`. As you're using Python 2.6 and this is only a thing in Python 2.7, you can install the [ordereddict](https://pypi.org/project/ordereddict/) package via PIP by running `pip install ordereddict`. Then:

```py
from ordereddict import OrderedDict

mydict = OrderedDict(sorted(mydict.items()))
```

Comment: In the question they mention that OrderedDict is not available to them.

Comment: python3.6 will preserve insert order as a part of the spec. Just make a new dict from the results with the `dict` constructor @CalderWhite

Comment: Thanks @CalderWhite, missed that one. In that case I'd suggest just sticking with the ordered list of tuples, otherwise OrderedDict functionality can be had in Python 2.6 with the [ordereddict PIP package](https://pypi.org/project/ordereddict/). I'll edit my answer to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

If you create your dictionary from a sorted list, it will be in the right order right away:

```
venue_dict = {name:False for name in sorted(venue_names)}
```

*Note that `venue_dict = sorted(venue_dict)` will change the `venue_dict` variable to a list because `sorted(venue_dict)` returns a list of keys, it does not sort the dictionary. This is probably why you are getting an error, on subsequent uses of venue_dict.*

BTW, if you're using an old version of Python (e.g. 2.7) the dictionaries do not have a defined order so there is no way to sort them at all.  You should  update to a recent version of Python or use a double indirection: e.g. access sorted list of names-> use name as subscript to dictionary.

I can't actually check this but I believe the constructor for the old version of OrderedDict would work the same way:

```
venue_dict = OrderedDict( (name,False) for name in sorted(venue_names) )
```

If all else fails, you could always access the dictionary from sorted keys:

```
venue_dict = dict()
for name in venue_names: venue_dict[name] = False

for name in sorted(venue_dict):
    print(name, venue_dict[name])
```

Comment: This dictionary comprehension probably only work on Python 3+.  I only have Python 3.7 installed so I can't actually check which version is needed.